# Is it possible to have a single frontend select between backends (defined dynamically)?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

I am currently looking into deploying Traefik/Træfik on our service fabric cluster.

Basically I have a setup where I have any number of Applications (services), defined with a tenant name and each of these services is in fact a separate Web UI.

I am trying to figure out if I can configure a single frontend to target a backend so I don't have to define a new frontend each time I deploy a new UI app. Something like

```
[frontend.tenantui]
rule = "HostRegexp:localhost,{tenantName:[a-z]+}.example.com"
backend = "fabric:/WebApp/{tenantName}"
```

The idea is to have it such that I can just deploy new UI services without updating the frontend configuration.

I am currently using the Service Fabric provider for my backend services, but I am open to using the file provider or something else if that is required.

**Update**:
The servicemanifset contains labels, so as to let traefik create backends and frontends.

The labels are defined for one service, lets call it `WebUI` as an example. Now when I deploy an instance of `WebUI` it gets a label and traefik understands it.

Then I deploy ANOTHER instance with a DIFFERENT set of parameters, its still the `WebUI` service and it uses the same manifest, so it gets the same labels, and the same routing. But what I would really want was to let it have a label containing some sort of rule so I could route to the name of the service instance (determine at runtime not design time). Specifically I would like for the runtime part to be part of the domainname (thus the suggestion of a HostRegexp style rule)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You do use Traefik labels within the service manifest to configure the routing? Maybe you could add more details to your current approach.

Comment: Added an update to clarify the need (hopefully it clarifies things)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use the matched group from the `HostRegexp` to determine the backend.

A possibility would be to use the [Property Manager API](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/servicefabric/#property-manager) to dynamically set the frontend rule for the service instance after creating it. Also, see [this](https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric/blob/master/Demos/scenarios/upgrade-bluegreen.ps1) for a complete example on using the API.